# xbean's inst2xsd : generate int instead of short/byte

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Does anyone knows how can I configure inst2xsd to generate `int` and not `byte` (nor `short`)?
I use the `-simple-content-types smart` (default) option.

see also [their online docs](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd).

10x, asaf :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my solution, due to the high demand:

#### generateXSD.bat:

```
inst2xsd -outDir xsd -outPrefix mySchema my.xml
```

#### compile.bat:

```
scomp -compiler "path_to\javac" -src mySrcDir -out lib\mySchema.jar xsd\mySchema.xsd xsdconfig\my.xsdconfig
```

#### Ant target:

```
<target name="xbean">
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="xbean">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="generateXSD.bat"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
    </exec>
    <replace file="xbean/xsd/mySchema.xsd" summary="yes">
        <replacefilter token="xs:byte" value="xs:int"/>
        <replacefilter token="xs:short" value="xs:int"/>
    </replace>
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="xbean">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="compile.bat"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

*Now back to me. I'm on a horse.*